# Page reload by jquery after ajax function

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

My code is working, except `location.reload();` is not working. My purpose is to reload the page after unchecking the last checkbox.

```js
$(".catcf, .coursetype, .yearcf, .manthcf, .venucf").on('click', function() {
  $checkedInputs = $('input.catcf:checked');
  $coursetypeInputs = $('input.coursetype:checked');
  $yearcfInputs = $('input.yearcf:checked');
  $manthcfInputs = $('input.manthcf:checked');
  $venucfInputs = $('input.venucf:checked');

  if (($checkedInputs.length > 0) || ($coursetypeInputs.length > 0) || ($yearcfInputs.length > 0) || ($manthcfInputs.length > 0) || ($venucfInputs.length > 0) || (styleviwe > 0)) {
    // Some AJAX code here...
  } else {
    // Here I can't reload the page with the last uncheck box but it's not working
    location.reload();
  }
});
```

Comment: Show your html code .

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the last condition:

```js
(styleviwe > 0)
```

```js
$(".catcf, .coursetype, .yearcf, .manthcf, .venucf").on('click', function() {
  $checkedInputs = $('input.catcf:checked');
  $coursetypeInputs = $('input.coursetype:checked');
  $yearcfInputs = $('input.yearcf:checked');
  $manthcfInputs = $('input.manthcf:checked');
  $venucfInputs = $('input.venucf:checked');

  if (($checkedInputs.length > 0) || ($coursetypeInputs.length > 0) || ($yearcfInputs.length > 0) || ($manthcfInputs.length > 0) || ($venucfInputs.length > 0)) {
    // Some AJAX code here...
  } else {
    // Here I can't reload the page with the last uncheck box but it's not working
    location.reload();
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="catcf" type="checkbox" checked />
<input class="coursetype" type="checkbox" checked />
<input class="yearcf" type="checkbox" checked />
<input class="manthcf" type="checkbox" checked />
<input class="venucf" type="checkbox" checked />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have added a snipped to show a working example. You can click on "Show code snippet" and "Run code snippet" to test it.